# How to restrict a note field to 255 characters (without switching to single line of text)

Tags: list, field-definition

I made a custom note field named "Content_Feedback" without specifying Allow Unlimited Length in document libraries

```
<Field
    ID="{C9C90E3A-85AB-492E-9E47-C7A520A7DD0D}"
    Name="Content_Feedback"
    DisplayName="Content Feedback"
    Type="Note"
    NumLines="8" 
    RichText="FALSE"
    Group="AXA">
</Field>
```

[image]
It should thus be limited to 255 characters since as far as I know, this property is responsible from changing it from a regular single line of text field definition.

The field is used by a content type which is not overriding this definition and finally by a custom list, redeclaring the field as it.

Unfortunately, it's possible to enter more than 255 characters in it. I made several tests on my dev machine ("works on my machine syndrome") back at the implementation time and anything above 255 characters was successfully & automatically trimmed. Now it's no more the case.

- Are you aware of anything in a recent CU that would have changed this (got this on both dec 2011 cu et June 2012 cu)
- Are you aware of anything that would prevent this limit ?
- Did I misunderstand the Unlimited Lenght in Document Libraries ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Why not use `MaxLength="255"`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would have if I was aware of that unexpected - for me - behavior of unlimited note field when omitting the unlimited length in document library. I don't think it has to do with a custom list for a document library. Thanks a lot for your input anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can put more then 255 chars in it using code. However using the SharePoint UI this should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience this is not applicable in SharePoint OOB however you can develop event receiver to check this field server side and client side you can use java script for validation, also not that MaxLength property will not work and you have to use javascript

hope this helps